# How to run sql query as entity value of table in linq to SQL in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I've table in SQL server 2008 r2 Like

```
Create Table Table1
(
  Col1 varchar(100)
)
```

Where I've records for Col1 as value are given below : 
  1. `select count(*) from Table2;`
  2. `select getDate();`

I'm using this table in my app using Linq to SQl in .dbml
How can I execute these queries and get returned value from that query in loop(1 by 1) using Linq? when I don't have exact return type of coming value. I tried ExecuteQuery() function but it needs type at compile time and my o/p can be any type as per query or function used in query.

Comment: If you're using Linq 2 Sql , you could create the corresponding class which matches the data type of your tables. There are some tools for it. Then you write a Linq query on that class.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx -- Follow this guide

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad: I created like as you mentioned, added some logic with ExecuteReader() function of contexts command object and it worked

Comment: Cool awesome :) appreciate people trying things rather than just looking for an answer